# javascript array within an array error

Tags: javascript

Hey Guys my goal for this multi dimensional array is to document the answers (right or wrong) for a test that the user is taking. In the beginning the test array is set up. as the user goes throught the questions the app should add to the array. Note: the page doesnt reload, the questions come via ajax.

Here is what i have so far

```
   var test = new array();

   function nextquestion(){
      var result;

    if (document.getElementById('rb2').checked = true){
  result = 'correct' ;
    }
else{

result = 'incorrect';
}
var num = document.getElementByName('rb').value;

var question =new Array(); 
question1[0]= document.getElementByName('rb').value; //question id    
question1[1]= result;
```

I want the test array to hold the data like so

```
   test[0]
  test[1][0] = question 1
  test[1][1] = correct
  test[2][0] = question 4
  test[2][1] = incorrect
  test[3][0] = question 17
  test[3][1] = correct
  test[4][0] = question 12
  test[4][1] = incorrect



  test[0]
  test[1][0] = question 1
  test[1][1] = correct
  test[2][0] = question 2
  test[2][1] = incorrect
  test[3][0] = question 3
  test[3][1] = correct
  test[4][0] = question 4
  test[4][1] = incorrect
```

also what must i add to the next function to get the value of the question id so that i can + 1 to get the next question from the database

thanks in advance!!

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('rb2').checked = true)` is a problem: don't say `.checked = true` (assignment), say `.checked === true` (comparison). Or, given that the `.checked` property is a boolean you don't need the comparison at all: `if (document.getElementById('rb2').checked) {}`. Also the first line of your code should reference `Array()` with a capital "A", or, better: `var test = []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want elements of your `test` array to hold other arrays, you have to set that up manually:

```
var test = [];
test.push([]);
test[0].push("Question 1");
test[0].push(true); //or "correct"

var q1 = test[0][0];
//"Question 1"

var wasQ1Correct = test[0][1];
//true
```

And so on